# clear suggestion box of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a lo-gin   page in that i just want to clear suggestion box like if 10 users lo-gin from that lo-gin page and when 11 user try to lo-gin from same lo-gin page and when he click on that input field he gives all 10 the names as suggestion  i don't want that user know the  name of previously lo-gin users please help i already tried autocomplete in input field as well as on form but it won't help I'm a fresher if i made any mistake in writing please consider...

```
<input class="input-field" id="userName" name="userName" type="text">.
```

Comment: please check the the question before mark it as duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

Try `autocomplete` property of input:

```
<input class="input-field" id="userName" name="userName" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: i tried autocomplete="off" but if clears the field at the time of page loading but when i click on input field it gives me list of previous login users

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: It worked on Chrome browser!

Comment: doesnt work in edge(laravel/blade)